# TSQL Select only the highest credentail

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that is returning multiple line for a single service because an individual may have multiple credentials. In the medical field you retain several credentials but for simplicity sake I will use just standard credentials Phd, MA, MS, BA, BS, AS

I need to know the simplest way to ignore rows where Z_ServiceLedger.clientvisit_id has any Credentials.credentials lower in the hierarchy. So if an employee does a service and he has a Phd and a MA only return the lines for Phd and if he has a Phd an Ma and a BA only return the lines for phd.  We have around 50 credentials so if I use CASE for each credential you can see how mess that will get an I'm hoping there is a better way to avoid that.

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.non_billable = 0 THEN v.duration ELSE 0 END) / 60 AS billable_hours,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (v.non_billable = 0 AND Z_ServiceLedger.payer_id = 63) THEN v.duration ELSE 0 END) / 60 AS billable_mro_hours,
    Credentials.credentials
FROM 
    Z_ServiceLedger
INNER JOIN 
    ClientVisit v ON Z_ServiceLedger.clientvisit_id = v.clientvisit_id
LEFT JOIN 
    Employees ON v.emp_id = Employees.emp_id
LEFT JOIN 
    EmployeeCredential ON Employees.emp_id = EmployeeCredential.emp_id
LEFT JOIN 
    Credentials ON Credentials.credential_id = EmployeeCredential.credential_id
WHERE 
    v.rev_timein <= CASE
                       WHEN EmployeeCredential.end_date IS NOT NULL 
                          THEN EmployeeCredential.end_date 
                          ELSE GETDATE()
                       END 
    AND v.rev_timein >= @param1 
    AND v.rev_timein < DateAdd(d, 1, @param2) 
    AND Z_ServiceLedger.amount > 0 
    AND v.splitprimary_clientvisit_id IS NULL
    AND v.gcode_primary_clientvisit_id IS NULL 
    AND v.non_billable = 0
    AND v.non_billable = 'FALSE' 
    AND v.duration / 60 > 0 
    AND Z_ServiceLedger.action_type NOT IN ('SERVICE RATE CHANGE', 'CLIENT STATEMENT') 
    AND (EmployeeCredential.is_primary IS NULL OR EmployeeCredential.is_primary != 'False') 
    AND v.client_id != '331771 '
GROUP BY 
    Credentials.credentials,
    v.non_billable
ORDER BY 
    Credentials.credentials
```

Comment: Do you have some way that credentials are currently ranked in the database?

Comment: I would suggest create a table with all the credentials and give them a weightage based on your preference, then you can join result from above query to this new table and select row with max value

Comment: And what if you have someone with 2 Master's and 1 Bachelor's degree?  How does that go into the database?  All 3 go in?

Comment: I would suggest you take 3-5 minutes and format this into something legible. It is currently a wall of text query. And when you start seeing things like distinct and group by in the same query it is a good indication something has gone wrong as both of them is redundant.

Comment: You have a lot of filter conditions in the `WHERE` clause when they may be better suited as part of your `JOIN`, depending on how you need to filter out your data. It would clean up the code and the data. And what is the datatype of `EmployeeCredential.is_primary`? If it's an actual `bit` then you wouldn't want to filter on the `'FALSE'` string, but with an actual boolean value. (And that's one of the filters that will effect the final number of rows your query returns.)

Comment: @KarthikGanesan Ok, I have sent a request to the persons who can give me those weights and I'll have to create a temp table #temp with columns 'credentials' and 'weight'. How would I implement that into the current query?

Comment: @Bryan You wouldn't really want a temp table unless there is no other option. This is a design oversight. The weighting should be added to the table that holds the credentials.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

Some aliases and formatting really shed some light on some major logical flaws here. You have at least two predicates in your where clause that logically turn a left join into an inner join. This is total shot in the dark since from both of your questions today we don't have anything to actually work with for tables or sample data.

The biggest concern though is your where clause is trying to get rows v.non_billable = 0 and where it equals 'FALSE'. It can't be both.

```
Select sum(Case When v.non_billable = 0 Then v.duration Else 0 End) / 60 As billable_hours
    , sum(Case When (v.non_billable = 0 And sl.payer_id = 63) Then v.duration Else 0 End) / 60 As billable_mro_hours
    , c.credentials
From Z_ServiceLedger sl
Inner Join ClientVisit v On sl.clientvisit_id = v.clientvisit_id
Left Join Employees e On v.emp_id = e.emp_id
Left Join EmployeeCredential ec On e.emp_id = ec.emp_id
                        --if you leave these predicates in the where clause you have turned your left join into an inner join.
                        AND v.rev_timein <= isnull(ec.end_date, GetDate()) 
                        and (ec.is_primary Is Null Or ec.is_primary != 'False')                     
Left Join Credentials c On c.credential_id = ec.credential_id
Where v.rev_timein >= @param1 
    And v.rev_timein < DateAdd(day, 1, @param2) 
    And v.splitprimary_clientvisit_id Is Null
    And v.gcode_primary_clientvisit_id Is Null
    --you need to pick one value for v.non_billable. It can't be both 0 and 'FALSE' at the same time. 
    And v.non_billable = 0 
    And v.non_billable = 'FALSE' 
    --And v.duration / 60 > 0 
    and v.duration > 60 --this is the same thing and is SARGable
    And sl.amount > 0 
    And sl.action_type NOT IN ('SERVICE RATE CHANGE', 'CLIENT STATEMENT') 
    And v.client_id != '331771 '
Group By c.credentials
    , v.non_billable
Order By c.credentials
```

Comment: "The biggest concern though is your where clause is trying to get rows v.non_billable = 0 and where it equals 'FALSE'. It can't be both." >> Technically, I think it "can" because those two values should be coercible to comparable values, but I agree that it shows a fault in the logic of that column. And I'm glad you pointed out the issues with the `LEFT JOIN` logic there. I'm more concerned with the implication that `is_primary = NULL'  means that `is_primary` is essentially `TRUE`.

Comment: Personally, I think that either we haven't been given enough information to actually understand this design, or this design warrants a re-think.

Comment: @Shawn I totally agree. I posted this at least a partial answer to deal with some of the serious issues and/or a good reason to revisit the design phase.

Comment: You guys are correct, the = 'FALSE' should have never been there. interestingly enough it doesn't affect the results at all which is odd. I have no doubt the DB could be redesigned but unfortunately it's not mine.Our medical records are cloud based so I don't even have access to the schema. I have limited access through a web interface to write queries to run reports against the data. I've only been with this company a few months and come from a minimal MySQL background into a corporate cloud hosted SQL-server with very limited access so I apologize for my sloppy query.

Comment: @Bryan So this query is being run in code and not on the database itself? If at all possible, parts of this would be much more suited to a View. This query is going to beat on the database pretty hard.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Modified query to add a CTE to calculate the `credential_rank`, using a `FROM (VALUES (...))` table-value-constructor syntax. This works in SQL 2008+. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b74d3/3)

First, I'll build out a very simple piece of data.

**SETUP**:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees ( emp_id int, emp_name varchar(20) ) ;
INSERT INTO Employees (emp_id, emp_name)
VALUES (1,'Jay'),(2,'Bob')
;

CREATE TABLE Credentials ( credential_id int, credentials varchar(20), credential_rank int ) ;
INSERT INTO Credentials (credential_id, credentials, credential_rank)
VALUES (1,'BA',3),(2,'MA',2),(3,'PhD',1)
;

CREATE TABLE EmployeeCredential (emp_id int, credential_id int, is_primary bit, end_date date )
INSERT INTO EmployeeCredential (emp_id, credential_id, is_primary, end_date)
VALUES 
    ( 1,2,null,'20200101' )
  , ( 1,3,0,'20200101' ) /* NON-PRIMARY */
  , ( 1,1,1,'20100101' ) /* EXPIRED CRED */
  , ( 2,3,null,'20200101' )
  , ( 2,3,1,'20200101' )
;

CREATE TABLE z_ServiceLedger ( payer_id int, clientvisit_id int, amount int, action_type varchar(50) ) ;
INSERT INTO z_ServiceLedger ( payer_id, clientvisit_id, amount, action_type )
VALUES (63,1,10,'XXXXX'),(63,2,20,'XXXXX'),(63,3,10,'XXXXX'),(63,4,30,'XXXXX') 
;

CREATE TABLE ClientVisit ( clientvisit_id int, client_id int, non_billable bit, duration int, emp_id int , rev_timein date, splitprimary_clientvisit_id int, gcode_primary_clientvisit_id int ) ;
INSERT INTO ClientVisit ( clientvisit_id, client_id, non_billable, duration, emp_id, rev_timein, splitprimary_clientvisit_id, gcode_primary_clientvisit_id )
VALUES
    (1, 1234, 0, 110, 1, getDate(), null, null ) 
  , (2, 1234, null, 120, 1, getDate(), null, null ) 
  , (3, 1234, 1, 110, 2, getDate(), null, null ) 
  , (4, 1234, 0, 130, 2, getDate(), null, null ) 
;
```

**MAIN QUERY**:

```
; WITH creds AS (
  SELECT c.credential_id, c.credentials, r.credential_rank
  FROM Credentials c 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (VALUES (1,3),(2,2),(3,1) ) r(credential_id, credential_rank)
    ON c.credential_id = r.credential_id
)    
SELECT DISTINCT
    SUM(CASE WHEN ISNULL(v.non_billable,1) = 0 THEN v.duration ELSE 0 END)*1.0 / 60 AS billable_hours,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (ISNULL(v.non_billable,1) = 0 AND zsl.payer_id = 63) THEN v.duration ELSE 0 END)*1.0 / 60 AS billable_mro_hours,
    s2.credentials
FROM Z_ServiceLedger zsl
INNER JOIN ClientVisit v ON zsl.clientvisit_id = v.clientvisit_id
    AND v.rev_timein >= @param1
    AND v.rev_timein < DateAdd(d, 1, @param2) 
    AND v.splitprimary_clientvisit_id IS NULL
    AND v.gcode_primary_clientvisit_id IS NULL 
    AND ISNULL(v.non_billable,1) = 0
    AND v.duration*1.0 / 60 > 0 
    AND v.client_id <> 331771
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT s1.emp_id, s1.emp_name, s1.credential_id, s1.credentials, s1.endDate
  FROM (
    SELECT e.emp_id, e.emp_name, c.credential_id, c.credentials, ISNULL(ec.end_date,GETDATE()) AS endDate 
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.emp_id ORDER BY c.credential_rank) AS rn
    FROM Employees e
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  EmployeeCredential ec ON e.emp_id = ec.emp_id
      AND ISNULL(ec.is_primary,1) <> 0 /* I don't think a NULL is_primary should be TRUE */
    LEFT OUTER JOIN creds c ON ec.credential_id = c.credential_id
  ) s1
  WHERE s1.rn = 1
) s2 ON v.emp_id = s2.emp_id
  AND v.rev_timein <= s2.endDate /* Credential not expired at rev_timein */
WHERE zsl.amount > 0 
  AND zsl.action_type NOT IN ('SERVICE RATE CHANGE', 'CLIENT STATEMENT') 
GROUP BY s2.credentials
ORDER BY s2.credentials
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b74d3/3/0)**:

```
| billable_hours | billable_mro_hours | credentials |
|----------------|--------------------|-------------|
|       1.833333 |           1.833333 |          MA |
|       2.166666 |           2.166666 |         PhD |
```

A couple of things to watch for:

1) Integer Division : `duration/60` will return an integer. So if you had `duration=70`, then you'd have 70/60 = 1. You'd miss that 10 minutes, because of the result will be converted back to an integer. You lose that extra 10 minutes. Probably not what you inteded. The easiest solution is to just multiply `duration` by `1.0` so that it is forced into a decimal datatype and won't cause the operation to be treated like integers.

2) `EmployeeCredential.is_primary != 'False'` : Rather than account for the strings of "True"/"False", you should use an actual boolean value (1/0). And a `NULL` value should indicate that the value is `NOT TRUE` or `FALSE` rather than implying `TRUE`. Also, in SQL, `!=` will work to indicate `NOT EQUAL TO`, but you should use `<>` instead. It means the same thing, but is grammatically more correct for SQL.

3) `v.non_billable = 0 AND v.non_billable = 'FALSE'` : This can be shortened to `ISNULL(v.non_billable,1)=0` to short-circuit both checks, especially since `non_billable` can be `NULL`. You also avoid the implicit type converstion when comparing the number 0 and the string 'False'.

4) `v.client_id != '331771 '` : Change to `v.client_id<>33171`. First, the `!=` to `<>` that I mentioned earlier. Then `'331771'` is implicitly converted to a number. You should avoid implicit conversions.

5) You originally had `v.non_billable` in your `GROUP BY`. Since you aren't including it in your `SELECT`, you can't use it to `GROUP BY`. Also, you're already filtering out everything other than `non_billable=0`, so you'd never have more than one value to `GROUP BY` anyway. Just exclude it.

6) `CASE WHEN EmployeeCredential.end_date IS NOT NULL THEN EmployeeCredential.end_date ELSE GETDATE() END` : This is the same as saying `ISNULL(EmployeeCredential.end_date,GETDATE())`.

7) Unless you actually need to filter out specific records for a specific reason, more your `JOIN` conditions into the `JOIN` rather than using them in the `WHERE` clause. This will help you be more efficient with the data your initial query returns before it is filtered or reduced. Also, when using a `WHERE` filter with a `LEFT JOIN`, you may end up with unexpected results.

Comment: The query will likely need to be edited to account for your data (especially ranking of the `Credentials` and the use of `NULL` in `non_billable`). You'll also want to test it with your data. I don't really like the execution plan it created, and the query does a lot of work that could be improved with indexing or SQL Views.

Comment: unfortunately I don't have access to CREATE as this is a hosted cloud MRO app. All queries have to start with Select as well or they are rejected so I was trying to figure out how to build a temp table inserting (Rank, Credential) but it's possible? It's a serious pain working around all these restrictions.

Comment: @Bryan I updated my query to use a CTE for the credential ranking. If your hosted solution can't use a CTE (query starts with `WITH`), then you want to have a serious discussion with them about not allowing modern SQL syntax. If they refuse to fix their system to allow for valid syntax, then you can move the CTE into a subquery (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b74d3/4). But that will make the query significantly less efficient.